# $R$ is commutative, $I$,$J$ are ideals, $I+J=R$, then $IJ=I\cap J$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ and $J$ are ideals s.t. $I+J=R$ then show that $IJ=I\cap J$.

I've already shown that $IJ \subset I\cap J$, now I need to show the reverse inclusion.

I'm a bit lost, so far i'm just figuring out what pieces I have to work with.

Such as:

$\forall r\in R$ $\exists i\in I ,j\in J$ s.t. $i+j=r$

$\forall ij\in IJ$, $ij=i_1$ and $ij=j_1$ for some $i_1\in I$, $j_1\in J$.

Also, if I let $x\in I\cap J$, then $x=i_2=j_2=i+j$ for some $i_2\in I$, $j_2\in J$

Anyone, having problem getting to the conclusion here, thanks in advance

Comment: Is $I\subset IJ$? How about $J$?

Comment: @JohnDouma It's very doubtful that $I$ is a subset of $IJ$. Take for instance, $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $I = 2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $J = 3 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$I \cap J = (I \cap J) \cdot R \\ = (I \cap J) \cdot (I + J) \\ = (I \cap J) \cdot I + (I \cap J) \cdot J \\ \subseteq IJ + IJ  \\ = IJ.$

Comment: what does the dot operator mean here?

Comment: I think it is just Ideal multiplication. i.e. if $I$ and $J$ are Ideals in the same ring $R$, then $I \cdot J = \{a_1 \cdot b_1 + ... + a_n \cdot b_n | a_i \in I, b_i \in J, n \in Z^+ \}$. This is all the finite sums of products of elements of $I$ and $J$. And yes, that is also an ideal and it distributes over the sum of ideals.

Comment: There is obviously nothing wrong with this proof, but I feel like a student who needs to see a proof that $I+J=R \Rightarrow I\cap J=IJ$ would also need to see an element-wise proof of the various equalities contained in this proof.

Answer (score 13):

There are $i\in I, j\in J$ such that $i+j=1$. Then, for all $a\in I\cap J$,
$$a=a1=a(i+j)=ai+aj\in JI+IJ=IJ.$$

Comment: This proof need not to be true in general. Because there are commutative rings without unity; for example, $R=2 \mathbb Z$.